# Custom spray-json RootJsonFormat or JsonFormat depending on value in JSON object

Tags: json, scala, akka, akka-stream, spray-json

In an Akka streams connection I receive JSON objects that looks like this:

```
{"op":"connection"...}
{"op":"status"...}
..etc
```

And I have a the following classes setup:

```
case class ResponseMessage(
  op: Option[OpType],
)

case class ConnectionMessage(
  a: Option[Int],
  b: Option[Int],
) extends ResponseMessage

case class StatusMessage(
  c: Option[Int],
  d: Option[Int],
) extends ResponseMessage

type OpTypes = OpTypes.Value
object OpTypes extends Enumeration {
  val Connection = Value("connection")
  val Status = Value("status")
```

> How can I write custom JsonFormat instances so that depending on the
>   value of `op` I create the correct type?
>   So that it can be used as such:

```
> jsValue.convertTo[ResponseMessage] And the outvalue will be either
> ConnectionMessage or StatusMessage?
```

Comment: will this work..  a pattern match may be
op.value match {
"Connection"=>Value("Connection")
"Status"=>Value("Status")
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: it's not best practice to extend case class i.e. ResponseMessage.  Google "case class inheritance"...

About your question on `JsonFormat`, I'd define specific `JsonFormat`s for each subclass, and then define the one for `ResponseMessage` base on those like:

```
import spray.json._

abstract class ResponseMessage(val op: Option[OpTypes])
object ResponseMessage {
  implicit object jsonFormat extends JsonFormat[ResponseMessage] {
    override def read(json: JsValue): ResponseMessage = json match {
      case JsObject(fields) =>
        fields.get("op") match {
          case Some(JsString("connection")) => json.convertTo[ConnectionMessage]
          case Some(JsString("status")) => json.convertTo[StatusMessage]
          case op => // unknown op
        }
      case _ => // invalid json
    }

    override def write(obj: ResponseMessage): JsValue = obj match {
      case connection: ConnectionMessage => connection.toJson
      case status: StatusMessage => status.toJson
    }
  }
}

case class ConnectionMessage(
                              a: Option[Int],
                              b: Option[Int]
                            ) extends ResponseMessage(Some(OpTypes.Connection))
object ConnectionMessage {
  implicit object jsonFormat extends JsonFormat[ConnectionMessage] {
    override def read(json: JsValue): ConnectionMessage =
      // json -> ConnectionMessage

    override def write(obj: ConnectionMessage): JsValue =
      // ConnectionMessage -> json
  }
}

case class StatusMessage(
                          c: Option[Int],
                          d: Option[Int]
                        ) extends ResponseMessage(Some(OpTypes.Status))
object StatusMessage {
  implicit object jsonFormat extends JsonFormat[StatusMessage] {
    override def read(json: JsValue): StatusMessage =
      // json -> StatusMessage

    override def write(obj: StatusMessage): JsValue =
      // StatusMessage -> json
  }
}

type OpTypes = OpTypes.Value

object OpTypes extends Enumeration {
  val Connection = Value("connection")
  val Status = Value("status")
}
```